# A simple determinant calculations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, determinant

I calculate the claim of the theorem below for a couple of times, always I get $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i z^{L+i}$ and not $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} c_i z^{L+M+i}$ as the coefficient of RHS of last determinant (i.e. the first determinant of 1.11 seems incorrect?)  :

[image]

Is the theorem incorrect or am I mistaken?

**Note : rows in P and Q are the same except for the last one.**

Comment: Simple calculations ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's a mental calculation, just use the properties of determinants; but I think the book is mistaken?

Comment: @YvesDaoust rows in P and Q are the same except for the last one!

Comment: No, they aren't. Determinants with identical rows are zero.

Comment: @TheMagicMountain  I believe that when you say "rows in P and Q are the same except for the last one!"  you mean that each row in P is identical to the corresponding row in Q, except for the last row.

Comment: @Ramiro, Yes! .

Answer (score 1):

Let us go step by step.

\begin{align*} 
Q^{[L/M]}&\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i z - P^{[L/M]}(z)= \\
& =\begin{vmatrix}
c_{L-M+1} & c_{L-M+2} & \cdots &  c_{L+1}\\
c_{L-M+2} & c_{L-M+3} & \cdots &  c_{L+2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{L-1} & c_{L} & \cdots &  c_{L+M -1}\\
c_{L} & c_{L+1} & \cdots &  c_{L+M}\\
\sum_{i=L-M+1}^\infty c_iz^{M+i} & \sum_{i=L-M+2}^\infty c_iz^{M+i-1} & \cdots & \sum_{i=L+1}^\infty c_iz^{i}
\end{vmatrix} = \\
& \\
& =\begin{vmatrix}
c_{L-M+1} & c_{L-M+2} & \cdots &  c_{L+1}\\
c_{L-M+2} & c_{L-M+3} & \cdots &  c_{L+2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{L-1} & c_{L} & \cdots &  c_{L+M -1}\\
c_{L} & c_{L+1} & \cdots &  c_{L+M}\\
\sum_{i=L-M+1}^{L} c_iz^{M+i} & \sum_{i=L-M+2}^{L+1} c_iz^{M+i-1} & \cdots & \sum_{i=L+1}^{L+M} c_iz^{i}
\end{vmatrix} + \\
&\phantom{mmm}+ \begin{vmatrix}
c_{L-M+1} & c_{L-M+2} & \cdots &  c_{L+1}\\
c_{L-M+2} & c_{L-M+3} & \cdots &  c_{L+2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{L-1} & c_{L} & \cdots &  c_{L+M -1}\\
c_{L} & c_{L+1} & \cdots &  c_{L+M}\\
\sum_{i=L+1}^\infty c_iz^{M+i} & \sum_{i=L+2}^\infty c_iz^{M+i-1} & \cdots & \sum_{i=L+M+1}^\infty c_iz^{i}
\end{vmatrix} = \\
& \\
& =0+\begin{vmatrix}
c_{L-M+1} & c_{L-M+2} & \cdots &  c_{L+1}\\
c_{L-M+2} & c_{L-M+3} & \cdots &  c_{L+2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{L-1} & c_{L} & \cdots &  c_{L+M -1}\\
c_{L} & c_{L+1} & \cdots &  c_{L+M}\\
\sum_{i=L+1}^\infty c_iz^{M+i} & \sum_{i=L+2}^\infty c_iz^{M+i-1} & \cdots & \sum_{i=L+M+1}^\infty c_iz^{i}
\end{vmatrix} = \\
&\\
& =\begin{vmatrix}
c_{L-M+1} & c_{L-M+2} & \cdots &  c_{L+1}\\
c_{L-M+2} & c_{L-M+3} & \cdots &  c_{L+2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{L-1} & c_{L} & \cdots &  c_{L+M -1}\\
c_{L} & c_{L+1} & \cdots &  c_{L+M}\\
\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_{L+i}z^{M+L+i} & \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_{L+1+i}z^{M+L+i} & \cdots & \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_{L+M+i}z^{M+L+i}
\end{vmatrix} = \\
&\\
& =\sum_{i=1}^\infty z^{M+L+i}\begin{vmatrix}
c_{L-M+1} & c_{L-M+2} & \cdots &  c_{L+1}\\
c_{L-M+2} & c_{L-M+3} & \cdots &  c_{L+2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{L-1} & c_{L} & \cdots &  c_{L+M -1}\\
c_{L} & c_{L+1} & \cdots &  c_{L+M}\\
c_{L+i} &  c_{L+1+i} & \cdots &  c_{L+M+i}
\end{vmatrix} = \\
&\\
& =\sum_{i=1}^\infty z^{L+M+i}\begin{vmatrix}
c_{L-M+1} & c_{L-M+2} & \cdots &  c_{L+1}\\
c_{L-M+2} & c_{L-M+3} & \cdots &  c_{L+2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
c_{L-1} & c_{L} & \cdots &  c_{L+M -1}\\
c_{L} & c_{L+1} & \cdots &  c_{L+M}\\
c_{L+i} &  c_{L+1+i} & \cdots &  c_{L+M+i}
\end{vmatrix} 
\end{align*}

Comment: @TheMagicMountain We write the determinant as the addition of two determinants. The first one is $0$ because its last row is the linear combination of the the rows above. That is how the $-M$ goes away.